# cURL command to php code

Tags: php, curl

```
curl -X GET \
     -H "X-Algolia-API-Key: ${API_KEY}" \
     -H "X-Algolia-Application-Id: ${APPLICATION_ID}" \
     --compressed \
    "https://status.algolia.com/1/status"
```

Can anyone please tell me how can i write this cURL command into php code?

Comment: Have you tried ***anything*** at all?

Comment: Here you can find about curl requests in php, http://codular.com/curl-with-php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Comment: and here how you can set custom header in curl request http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115683/php-curl-custom-headers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along these lines:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://status.algolia.com/1/status");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip");

$headers = array();
$headers[] = "X-Algolia-Api-Key: " . $api_key];
$headers[] = "X-Algolia-Application-Id: " . $application_id];
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the answers in [Curl PHP Run code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32329649/curl-php-run-code)
It should give you the info you need.